# Autoconf m4_bmatch not working with variable

Tags: bash, autotools, autoconf, m4, autoreconf

Here is some code in my configure.ac:

```
THIS="h5cc"
AC_MSG_WARN([$THIS])
AC_MSG_WARN(m4_bmatch([h5pcc],
         [h5pcc], [parallel],
         [h5cc], [serial],
         [neither]
         ))
AC_MSG_ERROR(m4_bmatch([$THIS],
         [h5pcc], [parallel],
         [h5cc], [serial],
         [neither]
         ))
```

I `autoconf` and then `configure`, which results in this:

```
configure: WARNING: h5cc
configure: WARNING: parallel
configure: error: neither
```

As far as I can tell, that's not supposed to happen, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Documentation for m4_bmatch: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Conditional-constructs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing M4 code within your configure, but m4 only executes before expansion (i.e. when you run `autoconf`), while `THIS=h5cc` is a shell construct that gets executed by your shell (when you run `./configure`).

So what `m4_bmatch` sees is a literal `$THIS` which indeed is neither.

Short version, don't use `m4_*` functions for things that you want to change at configure time.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `AS_CASE` instead (which is M4sh). See https://autotools.io/autoconf/m4sh.html (full disclosure, I wrote that.)

Comment: It is! I was just about to update your answer. I got it working.